# Changing a shortcut using Powershell

Tags: powershell, shortcut

So I'm needing to update a shortcut on our users PCs. I use PowerShell since our deployment software can run PowerShell scripts but I am running into an issue.
So if I use the following code to update the shortcut it works just fine.

```
$Comobj = New-Object -ComObject WScript.shell

$ShortCut = $ComObj.CreateShortcut("C:\Users\Public\Desktop\shortcut.lnk")

$ShortCut.TargetPath = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe dfshim.dll"

$ShortCut.save()
```

However the path needs to include a URL for it to function correctly like this example

```
$ShortCut.TargetPath = "C:\WINDOWS\system32\rundll32.exe dfshim.dll, ShOpenVerbApplication https://linkToServer.domain.ect"
```

when I run that as the target path I get a "value does not fall within expected range" error

I assume the error is because the path includes a URL even though the shortcut is a .lnk
when I change it manually in properties it works without complaints

is there something in PowerShell that will allow me to put in the full target path that I need?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Only the _executable path_ goes into `.TargetPath`; any _arguments_ to pass to it go into `.Arguments`. See the linked duplicate for details.